# Selectively add dlls to project via nuget

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Some dlls are used frequently in some projects in my company. So I already created one package which contain those dll files, let us just say `a.dll`, `b.dll`, `c.ll` and `d.dll`. Then I install this package via nuget to the project, all those four dll files will be added to the project. But I do not need all of them into each project, I may only need some of them. I try to delete the dll files which do not need. That`s all works fine.

Now my question is that all dll files will be re-added to the project after update that package. Obviously it is annoying to manually delete dll files after each update.

So is there a way for me to choose the dll files which I need to install when I install my package?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is there a way for me to choose the dll files which I need to install when I install my package?

As aware as I know you could not choose the dll files when you install your nuget package, at least now we can not do it.

According to the [nuget official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package):

[image]

When we including multiple dll file in the lib folder, nuget will automatically add those dll file into the project as references. This is nuget default behavior. Besides, updating a package simply means installing an updated version, this is equivalent to a re-installed behavior. So all dll files will be re-added to the project include those deleted files.

Since there are only four dll files in your project, I suggest that you can **pack each dll files into packages separately**. In this case, you do not need to add all dll files into your project, just install what you needed. Besides, we do not need to update the package in order to update one of dll file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I need pack those dll files separately. Thanks again.